# Hide formulas in excel without protecting the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to hid the formulas in my sheet without protecting the sheet,say i  have sheet 1 in that i need to hide the formulas from range(A1:G10) i can hide the formula but iam not able to provide input for  the whole sheet

My requirement is to hide the selected cells formulas and able to give inputs for other cells in the same sheet how can i achieve this.

Comment: You can hide the formula bar.

Comment: if i hide my formula bar others can unhide formula bar  and they can able to see @SJR

Comment: Your options are limited if you want to avoid protecting the sheet. Why can't you do that?

Comment: You need to be clearer in your questions. You said you wanted to avoid protecting the sheet but have accepted an answer which involves precisely that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the whole sheet, right click and then select `Format Cells...`. In the popup window, select `Protection` tab. Unselect both options and press `OK` button. This will unlock all cells on the sheet as by default all cells are locked. Next, select your range, repeat the above process again but this time ensure that both options (**`Locked`** and **`Hidden`**) are selected this time and press `OK`. Now protect your sheet (in Excel 2013, select the `REVIEW` tab and select `Protect Sheet` option and follow the steps). 
This will hide your formulas and stop anyone changing the values in the protected cells